# Oracle Update statement with if conditions

Tags: oracle, conditional-statements, sql-update

I'm trying to merge three update statements into one.

```
"UPDATE DOT_WORKS SET START_DATE = :StartDate WHERE ID = :WorksId and END_DATE IS NULL;"
"UPDATE DOT_WORKS SET WORKS_TYPE = :WorksType WHERE ID = WorksId and WORKS_GROUP = :WorksGroup;"
"UPDATE DOT_WORKS SET WORKS_CONNECTION = :WorksConn WHERE ID = WorksId and WORKS_PLACE = :WorksPlace;"
```

I'm wondering whether there is a way to do that.
The reason why I'm trying to do so is to save the calls to database. It's more efficient to call db once instead of three.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE DOT_WORKS 
SET START_DATE = case when END_DATE IS NULL then :StartDate else START_DATE end,
    WORKS_TYPE = case when WORKS_GROUP = :WorksGroup then :WorksType else WORKS_TYPE end,
    WORKS_CONNECTION = case when WORKS_PLACE = :WorksPlace then :WorksConn else WORKS_CONNECTION end
WHERE ID = :WorksId 
and 
(
  END_DATE IS NULL OR
  WORKS_GROUP = :WorksGroup OR
  WORKS_PLACE = :WorksPlace
)
```